# why the page is not refreshed after redirection to 'RedirectToRouteResult'?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013, filter, session-cookies

My filter is as follows

```
public class SessionExpireAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        HttpSessionStateBase session = filterContext.HttpContext.Session;   
        string userExpire = string.Empty;
        userExpire = new UserControllerHelper().FetchDataFromCookie(CookieField.UserRoleId.ToString());
        if (userExpire == "") 
        {
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Clear();
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary { { "controller", "Home" }, { "action", "Index" }, { "Area", "" } });
        }
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }       
}
```

This is getting redirected but the page is not refreshed. The expired url is still in the address bar.

I tried using the following code :

```
filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect(FormsAuthentication.LoginUrl);
```

But that's not at all redirected.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

try like this:

```
   filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary(
                new { area = "", controller = "Error", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, message = "CodeError", ErrorMessage = filterContext.Exception.GetBaseException().Message }));
```

Comment: I tried this without error message part but still its not refreshing